# Oracle adding a partition by year to timestamp column

Tags: oracle, database-partitioning

I have one Oracle table (my_table) with one timestamp column (my_column)
I´d like to add some partitions to the table by year

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD PARTITION BY RANGE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM my_column))
(
  PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2019),
  PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2020),
  PARTITION p_max VALUES LESS THAN (2100)
);
```

It says: "ORA-00902:tipo de dato no válido"

Any idea how to solve this?

thanks very much

Comment: As MT0s answer shows, don't convert a date or timestamp to a number like that. Keep it a date and use normal date intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_table
  MODIFY PARTITION BY
  RANGE(my_column)
  INTERVAL(INTERVAL '1' YEAR)
  (
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP '2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 00:00:00'),
    PARTITION p_max VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP '2100-01-01 00:00:00')
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I´ve tried that but it says: "ORA 14006: nombre de partición no válido"
Any idea what´s wrong with it? I don´t see anything wrong with names



Thanks again

Comment: I think the problem is oracle version

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

I´ll try to update it.

Thanks!